# Film over an SMD LED to change its colour?

Tags: led, surface-mount, rgb

I require an RGB white + amber LED SMD chip. Unfortunately, it looks like nobody really makes such a thing except for one seller on Aliexpress. I tried purchasing a few of these only to find their definition of amber is more of a burgundy/red/orange hue.

So instead I'm considering a 5050 5in1 RGBW CCT chip and somehow modifying the warm white chip to produce a more true amber/golden yellow colour.

Is there a suitable film that I can stick over the warm light side of the chip to convert it into more of an amber light?

[image]

The purpose of these LEDs is to illuminate a light guide that's only big enough to accept one chip, two is not possible otherwise a separate amber chip would have been my solution.

Comment: Kapton tape might do...

Comment: have you considered  separate leds and light pipes to channel the light into the light guide?

Comment: I can get RGBY/W LEDs but has a large MOQ

Comment: The idea of separate light pipes was exhausted in the end, it's such as tight spot and I'm only left with a diameter of 5mm on each pipe to play with unfortunately

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 would it be possible to share a link to the RGBYW chips? I'm not sure if it'll be a close enough colour temperature to amber, but it's worth a shot at checking out

Comment: I’m thinking of custom LEDs what CCT do you need or lambda D

Comment: Have you tried producing the desired function with just RGBW or RGB?

Answer (score 3):

Unless you investigate fluorescence, you can't get any colour out of a filter if it isn't already in the source. If the colour is off that much then you're going to need a lot of filtering to remove the deep red portion of the band that you've got and you won't be left with much light.

It's not clear from your question whether you need three different LEDs or one colour at a time. If the latter then your colour could be obtained by blending the RGB.

Comment: Yes that was one of my main worries, loosing brightness from the output would be a major blow for the project. RGB would be required when colour is introduced, however the main use would be white and amber - previous attempts with an RGB chip failed as the light guides gave off a blue/purple hue, so instead a dedicated white chip was required.

Comment: Was the blue/purple because the blue LED chip was centred on the light guide and was therefore stronger?

Comment: maybe try darkening the blue part of the LED,  perhaps use a series resistor or a magic marker.